# How do I efficiently map integers to URIs in a multidemnsional array?

Tags: python, dictionary, hash, encoding, vectorization

I have an array that looks something like this:

```
myarray = array([list(['string4', 'string2', 'string3']),list(['string1', 'string2', 'string4', 'string5']), list(['string1', 'string2', 'string4'])], dtype=object)
```

How do I encode the individual strings into integers? I have a large dataset. How would I do this most efficiently? I want something that looks like this:

```
myarrayencoded = [[4,2,3],[1,2,4,5],[1,2,4]]
```

Note: I cannot sort anything, as the position of the integers matters. Also, every sublist may contain a different amount of strings.

Comment: Maybe not an efficient one, but: `[[int(y[-1]) for y in x] for x in myarray]`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use Pandas via [`pd.factorize`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.23.4/generated/pandas.factorize.html), which uses hashing internally.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

myarray = np.array([list(['string4', 'string2', 'string3']),
                    list(['string1', 'string2', 'string4', 'string5']),
                    list(['string1', 'string2', 'string4'])], dtype=object)

flattened = np.concatenate(myarray)  # flatten array of lists
idx_split = np.array(list(map(len, myarray))).cumsum()[:-1]  # calculate split indices
factored = pd.factorize(flattened, sort=True)[0] + 1  # factorize, sort, start from 1

res = [i.tolist() for i in np.array_split(factored, idx_split)]  # return list of lists

print(res)

[[4, 2, 3], [1, 2, 4, 5], [1, 2, 4]]
```